# Form attribute :required => true missing from html output in production

Tags: java, jruby, glassfish-3, ruby-on-rails-2

Working on an apache server running glassfish with a ruby on rails application.

I've got a dev and production environment both running the same version of glassfish and java. For some reason when I load my application on my production environment any fields within a form that have an attribute like :required => true or :autocomplete => off aren't loaded into the html. On dev they load just fine. This probably means my environment are not exact.

I've checked both glassfish and java versions, which match. I uploaded the exact same WAR file to both environments, so I don't think it has anything to do with the application configuration itself. I've tried digging through both glassfish configs, but nothing stands out as being the issue. I also tried researching anything about Apache that may mess with those types of attributes, but came up with nothing.

Any solutions or thoughts on what to look at would be greatly appreciated.